# jquery append not working properly in my application

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a javascript which is generating the below html dynamically. I want those two dropdowns for all list elemnts. Here it is happening only for last list element.

```
<ul id="drivernvehicle">
    <li>
        <div class="form-group" id="1"></div>1.</li>
    <li>
        <div class="form-group" id="2"></div>2.</li>
    <li>
        <div class="form-group" id="3"></div>3.</li>
    <li>
        <div class="form-group" id="4"></div>4.
        <select class="form-control input-lg required">
            <option value="M" selected="selected">&lt;--select Driver--&gt;</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
        </select>
        <select class="form-control input-lg required">
            <option value="N" selected="selected">&lt;--select Vehicle--&gt;</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$('#drivernvehicle').empty();
var i = $('#noOfVehicle').val();
var j;
var temp;
var items = [];
for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    temp = j + 1;

    //var selectDiv = selectDiv + temp;
    var selectDiv = $("<li><div class=\"form-group\" id=\"" + temp + "\"></div></li>");
    selectDiv.append(temp + ". ")
             .append(driverSelectBox)
             .append(vehicleSelectBox);
    items.push(selectDiv);
}
$('ul#drivernvehicle').append(items);
```

javascript below which generate above html. here "driverSelectBox" and "vehicleSelectBox" are two dropdown which has been crated dynamically.

Comment: Did you try `$('ul#drivernvehicle li').append(items);`?

Comment: Can include `driverSelectBox` , `vehicleSelectBox` `js` , `html` ?

Comment: `#noOfVehicle` doesn't exist?

Comment: @Mottie  as 'li' i am creating dynamically so i can't select that tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have something to display.

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t8jo77Le/

I hardcoded/deleted the stuff you failed to include.

I added the 'Hello' here:

`$("<li><div class=\"form-group\" id=\"" + temp + "\">Hello</div></li>");`

Without it, it doesn't display.

Comment: No, for for string values as li item it is working but not for object. anyway i have found the solution all it needed was to clone the two select boxes otherwise it was not working. so now i have changed below two lines and it just works              .append(driverSelectBox.clone())
     .append(vehicleSelectBox.clone());   But thanks a lot for your answer.